# How do i adjust font size of a textblock with respect to the Text Length in Windows 8 xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am using a `Textblock` in a Listbox Template . Where i wants to vary the `Textblock Size` with respect to the `Content Text`. 
Small Text --> Large FontSize &&
Large Text --> Small font Size 
So that it filled in the template.
 How do we achieve this since Letters are taking varied occupied spaces.
 Example: 'i' takes less space than 'w' / Capital letters took more spaces than Small letters.

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Margin="355,101,0,0" Background="#FF139905">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a test application" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Margin="355,155,0,0" Background="#FF0FAA00">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is a test " Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13.333"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Margin="355,204,0,0" Background="#FF0FAA00">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="test " Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26.667"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: put the textblock in a Viewbox.

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted if it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

Put the textblock in a Viewbox.

```
<Viewbox>
   <TextBlock/>
</Viewbox>
```